# Backwards and Forwards Recurrence Relation for a Definite Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

So I have a question on an assignment that gives me a definite integral and tells me to get both the forwards and backwards recurrence. The problem is I don't really understand what that means.

I know that one way to get a recurrence from a definite integral is to use integration by part, but I'm not sure if this gives me the forwards one or the backwards one. So my question is, what version of the recurrence does using integration by parts give me and how do I get the other one?

Comment: Is it a specific integral? Of one variable, namely, $\int f(x) dx$? If so do you mean showing the recurrence between the definite integral with respect to the derivative of the function?

Comment: @JohnSmith It's a specific integral. As for your second question, I not sure. The only thing the question says is to "Derive both a forward and backwards recurrence for $I_n$." The follow question tell me to a reasonable initial value for each recurrence and the last ones says to plug them into MatLab script and compute a specific $I_n$